# File creation limits

Tags: php

Dear respective developer across the globe,

- I'm only seeking knowledge and understanding. Please provide as much

information as you can to not only help me out, but also others around the

world.

I will divide my questions so it's easier to understand what i'm asking for

and allow you to answer the questions individually for better

understanding.

My questions is:

**a)**

- I'm runing a home server using mamp pro on a windows 8 32gb ram, 4k ssd, i7 cpu.My server is dns is set with cloudflare.com. When people from the public world view my site there is a php script that create a text-file with their username. Like: {username}.txt. For every username. The same file get re-created everytime the user login to keep the data fresh about him. That was some information about what i'm doing. What i want to understand is. Is there any limits? let say 500000 people at same time try to reach my site and every user will make my site create a new fresh txt file for him. Will it work? is there any problem.. please share with me.

b)

Can a textfile get views by let say 1000000 as same time? i'm talking about viewed not created here.

Comment: Why not use a database? You're going to have huge problems with performance and consistency (not to mention security)  using flat files like this.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but mysql as exmaple only allowed to have 10k connections. I'm afraid that if the amount is more than 10k they will not get any data back...

Comment: Why not do some maths as to the size etc? Testing on performance?

Comment: Those 10k connections probably referred to 10k connections _at the same time_.

Comment: You seem to be focused entirely on scalability. Well, what you are describing doesn't scale. If you use MySQL or another database, you can scale by adding servers, load-balancing, etc. What you are describing is much more difficult to manage.

Answer (score 4):

The number of files is not limited at all by the operating system or by php.

But is *is* limited by the file system you safe the files in. The exact numbers depend on the type of file system and its configuration. Typical limits are 32000 inodes in a single directory. But as mentioned that can be configured.

What is typically done in such cases is that you spread all those files over directories, where the directories are named by a substring of the file name itself. So for example the file `somegoodguy.txt` is saved under `/som/ego/odg/somegoodguy.txt`. Provided you have a more or less equal usage of characters that should prevent that you hit any limits, since the files are equally spread over many, many folders.

---

However:

It is questionable if that is a good approach *at all*. File based storage is not exactly efficient. You get a *much* better performance if you use a database instead. One entry (row) per user in a database table. Accessing that information is really efficient and fast. And you don't have to worry about any limits.

Comment: There will be no problem regarding the  performance? speed in case for example "500000" view site almost same time..?

Comment: but a database like "mysql" only allow you to have 10k connections at max...i see a big limits here

Comment: You always have a slower reaction, the bigger the load gets. But certainly this will be _much_ faster than a file based approach!

Comment: I do not know where you read that about 10k connections. But as said above: Those 10k connections probably referred to 10k connections at the same time. You can trust in 50 years of computer science experience: database are much better suited for mass delivery than file systems. At least as long as the individual data chunks to not get too big.

Comment: so 500000 can easly connect to my mysql without any problem??

Comment: Over time, yes. At the same time? No. But that certainly is not a limitation of the database. It is a limitation of your computing power. Your "server" simply won't be able to handle all the requests. it will slow down, until some requests time out. That scenario is often called "DOS attack" btw :-) Do you _really_ think you will get 50000 hits _at the same time_?

Comment: what happens is somebody trying to connect at same time??? will he get no data or get the callback slower?

Comment: A few thousand connections in parallel, so at the same time is not the problem typically. But as said: it depends on your servers computation power. Not on the database.

Comment: What site is that going to be? 50000 hit per second already is a heavy load. Googles servers for example reach such numbers. But a private project someone starts? No way. You will not have that much parallel connections.

Comment: I'm sure the number will be more than 50000 hits :) - we are going to have a database and server for every country. Our app need to connect all country for use.. and we are afraid that it wont handle as much

Comment: If that _really_ is the case (I still doubt it), then you cannot serve that with a single server anyway. That is impossible. You will need to use load balancing over multiple systems, probably virtualized ones. You need to use CDNs. You need replication. You need to use automatic launch and pull down for servers.

Comment: I can't serve  50000 hits with a single mysgl server?

Comment: For the x-th time: the database server is _not_ the issue here. Your computation power is.

Comment: I'm understanding your point here. But what the needed  computation power to serve that amount?

Comment: Let me put it that way: what you ask is possible from a technical point of view. But it is not easy, it requires many technologies working together. Someone has to implement and maintain such a complex system. Someone with a lot of experience. Certainly not a single person, but a whole team of professionals.  Someone asking questions like what you ask certainly is not able to do that, sorry. _You will fail._

Comment: @sarahansen You will not be hitting those numbers anytime soon. As arkashka said, 50k hits/s is the kind of scale that Google or Amazon might reach. Your server will likely grind to a halt after a few hundred hits per second, anyway; certainly not 50k. Also, think about it this way: 50k hits/s is 4.3 billion hits/day. If you are getting that kind of traffic, then either (1) you have a truly terrible design for your application or (2) you can afford to scale up by a few (thousand) more servers. :)

Comment: Alright, but just to sum that up. I have ready that mysql have a max  of 10,000 connections. How come you say that 50000 hits would be no problem for mysql to handle itself?  so i undertsand by that, that if there is more than 10,000 connections ( at same time) somebody get a slower response right?

Comment: We said all there is to say. Please read our comments. Nothing more to say. Good luck!